# Upgrading Webpack from 2.7 to 4.35 blank page IE11

Tags: vuejs2, internet-explorer-11, upgrade, webpack-4

I'm working on a project where I want to update the Webpack 2.7 config to the newer 4.35 for optimization and cleaning purpose.
I rebuild from scratch my configuration, works on every browser (Firefox, Chrome, Edge) but not IE11.
No error in the console, a blank page.

I'm using SASS, SCSS, CSS, JS and Vue

I tried to use the previous configuration but I have to update to many things and I failed to compile in the end.
I try not to upgrade every package but only Webpack and the ones that needed to upgrade for compatibility purpose.
I also already tried Vue-CLI as it's a Vue project, but same issue. I needed to rewrite every predefined configuration to work for my project...

Previous package.json

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A Vue.js project",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node build/dev-server.js",
    "start": "node build/dev-server.js",
    "build": "node build/build.js",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "^3.2.89",
    "@progress/kendo-dateinputs-vue-wrapper": "^2018.3.1025",
    "@progress/kendo-inputs-vue-wrapper": "^2018.3.1025",
    "@progress/kendo-popups-vue-wrapper": "^2018.3.1025",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap": "^2.18.0",
    "@progress/kendo-ui": "^2018.3.1219",
    "@progress/kendo-validator-vue-wrapper": "^2018.3.1025",
    "animate.css": "^3.5.2",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "axios-retry": "^3.1.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "block-ui": "^2.70.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.21",
    "chart.piecelabel.js": "^0.11.0",
    "country-region-data": "^1.4.5",
    "emitter-io": "^1.25.0",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.4",
    "fast-json-patch": "^2.0.6",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "inputmask": "^4.0.0",
    "intersection-observer": "^0.5.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "jsplumb": "^2.8.8",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.20",
    "oidc-client": "^1.6.1",
    "progress-tracker": "^1.4.0",
    "rgbcolor": "^1.0.1",
    "stackblur": "^1.0.0",
    "svg.js": "^2.6.5",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "vee-validate": "^2.2.8",
    "vue": "^2.6.8",
    "vue-axios": "^2.1.4",
    "vue-chartjs": "^3.3.2",
    "vue-clickaway": "^2.2.2",
    "vue-cropperjs": "^2.2.2",
    "vue-i18n": "^7.8.1",
    "vue-js-toggle-button": "^1.3.2",
    "vue-loading": "^0.1.4",
    "vue-lodash": "^2.0.0",
    "vue-multiselect": "^2.1.6",
    "vue-observe-visibility": "^0.4.3",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-session": "^1.0.0",
    "vue-swatches": "^1.0.3",
    "vue-tippy": "^2.1.0",
    "vue2-dropzone": "^3.5.2",
    "vuedraggable": "^2.16.0",
    "vuejs-datepicker": "git+https://github.com/brurubio/vuejs-datepicker.git#build",
    "vuejs-jwt": "^1.1.0",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.2.6",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "chalk": "^2.4.1",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.5.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^3.2.2",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^2.3.1",
    "eventsource-polyfill": "^0.9.6",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.7.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.19.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "opn": "^5.3.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ora": "^1.4.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.7",
    "sass-resources-loader": "^1.3.3",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "svg-inline-loader": "^0.8.0",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.1",
    "vue-loader": "^13.7.1",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.8",
    "webpack": "^2.7.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.11.3",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.12.2",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.22.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

New package.json

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A Vue.js project",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --mode development --config webpack.dev.js --open --display-error-details",
    "start": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js build/dev-server.js",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js --mode production",
    "lint": "eslint --fix --ext .js,.vue src"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "^3.2.89",
    "@progress/kendo-dateinputs-vue-wrapper": "^2018.3.1025",
    "@progress/kendo-inputs-vue-wrapper": "^2018.3.1025",
    "@progress/kendo-popups-vue-wrapper": "^2018.3.1025",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap": "^2.18.0",
    "@progress/kendo-ui": "^2018.3.1219",
    "@progress/kendo-validator-vue-wrapper": "^2018.3.1025",
    "animate.css": "^3.5.2",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "axios-retry": "^3.1.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "block-ui": "^2.70.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.21",
    "chart.piecelabel.js": "^0.11.0",
    "country-region-data": "^1.4.5",
    "emitter-io": "^1.25.0",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.4",
    "fast-json-patch": "^2.0.6",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "inputmask": "^4.0.0",
    "intersection-observer": "^0.5.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "jsplumb": "^2.8.8",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.20",
    "oidc-client": "^1.6.1",
    "progress-tracker": "^1.4.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.2",
    "svg.js": "^2.6.5",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "vee-validate": "^2.2.8",
    "vue": "^2.6.8",
    "vue-axios": "^2.1.4",
    "vue-chartjs": "^3.3.2",
    "vue-clickaway": "^2.2.2",
    "vue-cropperjs": "^2.2.2",
    "vue-i18n": "^7.8.1",
    "vue-js-toggle-button": "^1.3.2",
    "vue-loading": "^0.1.4",
    "vue-lodash": "^2.0.0",
    "vue-multiselect": "^2.1.6",
    "vue-observe-visibility": "^0.4.3",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-session": "^1.0.0",
    "vue-swatches": "^1.0.3",
    "vue-tippy": "^2.1.0",
    "vue2-dropzone": "^3.5.2",
    "vuedraggable": "^2.16.0",
    "vuejs-datepicker": "git+https://github.com/brurubio/vuejs-datepicker.git#build",
    "vuejs-jwt": "^1.1.0",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.2.6",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "chalk": "^2.4.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.5.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^3.2.2",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^2.3.1",
    "eventsource-polyfill": "^0.9.6",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.7.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.19.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.7.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "opn": "^5.3.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ora": "^1.4.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.7",
    "sass-resources-loader": "^1.3.5",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "svg-inline-loader": "^0.8.0",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.1",
    "vue-loader": "^15.7.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.8",
    "webpack": "^4.35.3",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.11.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.5",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.12.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.7.2",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.22.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

I want to have some error or something to tell me that it's the use of a particular library or something, I'm desesperate...

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Possibly an issue with your babel setup. I'm not familiar with v6, but I'd suggest upgrading to v7 and using https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env. Seems like you may be missing polyfills for IE 11 that may require additional babel plugins.

Comment: And double check your webpack build console output for warnings or errors.

Comment: The config I’m using with my current babel work with webpack 2.7. I also tried babel 7 and preset env but no succes and no warning or error in webpack. And can’t know if IE11 is missing some polyfill as I have no error...

Comment: Please check the main.ts file, make sure it contains the babel-polyfill package and make sure it at the top of the entry point to ensure the polyfill are loaded first. If still not working, try to use F12 developer tools to check whether it contains some error?

Comment: I just tried to start from the project that work on IE11 and just update babel to the new version, don't start on IE11 and no error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it !
Was a babel not configured properly! Now it works !
Strange enough I had to force transpile another npm package...